# Matrix norms translating with identity matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, normed-spaces, upper-lower-bounds, adjoint-operators

Let $\mathcal{A}$ denote a linear operator, $\mathcal{A}^*$ its adjoint, and $\text{I}$ the identity matrix. Is the norm of $\mathcal{A}$ related to the norm of $\mathcal{A}^* \mathcal{A} - \text{I}$?

In particular, is it true that if

$\|\mathcal{A}^* \mathcal{A} - \text{I}\| \le 1/4$

then

$\|\mathcal{A}^* \mathcal{A}\| \ge 3/4$? If it is, why?

We know that $\|\mathcal{A}\|^2= \|\mathcal{A}^* \mathcal{A}\|$. I attempted proving it separating the norm of the difference with the triangle inequality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The operator norm satisfies the triangle inequality, in particular:
$$\Vert \mathrm I \Vert \leq \Vert \mathcal A^* \mathcal A \Vert + \Vert \mathrm I - \mathcal A^* \mathcal A \Vert \,,$$
so that
$$\Vert \mathcal A^* \mathcal A \Vert \geq 1 - \Vert \mathcal A^* \mathcal A - \mathrm I\Vert \,.$$

Comment: Thanks! From the triangle inequality we have that $\|\mathcal{A}^* \mathcal{A} - \text{I}\| \le \|\mathcal{A}^* \mathcal{A}\| + \|\text{I}\|$. How is the first expression in your answer obtained from this?

Comment: It is not obtained from that. Apply the triangle inequality to $\mathrm I = \mathcal A^* \mathcal A + (\mathrm I - \mathcal A^* \mathcal A)$.